# ReactJS Sign up page errors

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make a website log in page but I'm getting some error and I don't know why. Can somebody tell me why?
[This is the first error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRNAW.png)
If i put the semicolom there I will have another 
[And this is the second after "correction"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngr4G.png)

Here is my code:

```
setInputValue(property, val) {
        val = val.trim();
        if (val.length > 12) {
            return;
        }
        this.setState({
            [property]: val
        })
    }
    resetForm() {
        this.setState({
            username: '',
            password: '',
            buttonDisabled: false
        })
    }
}

    let result = await res.json();
    if (result && result.succes) {
        UserStore.isLoggedIn = true;
        UserStore.username = result.username;
    }

    else if (result && reult.succes === false) {
        this.resetForm();
        alert(result.msg);
    }
    catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
        this.resetForm();
    }
```

Comment: Look at your curly braces, looks like there's the wrong amount.

Comment: Based on the code you posted it appears there is an extra `}` after resetForm block. Also need more context but is your code after `let result = `... in the class definition? That's not valid JS.